# scrollable is not a known element error in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on this angular2 project and recently upgraded my project to angular2 final release.

Previously I was using angular2 RC5 for development and it worked fine but after I upgraded my project to final release I am getting below error :

> scrollable is not a known element

If I am changing

`<scrollable><!--- angular code --></scrollable>` to

`<div><!--- angular code --></div>`

then its working fine, but I am not able to scroll the page.

I am using angular-cli@latest.

In my browser console I am getting below messages:

> 1.if 'scrollable' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
>   2. If 'scrollable' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message

I really cant figure out why this is happening.

any inputs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ScrollableComponent],
  ...
})
class AppModule
```

Comment: I had already imported BrowserModule in my app.module. @Gunter